# New to VBA- runtime error 6, script stops at blank cells instead of looping

Tags: vba, excel, loops, integer-overflow

Recently started working with VBA.  Youtube and this forum have been excellent help so far.  However,  my problem is this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1

    Do While Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value <> 0
       Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1)
       i = i + 1
    Loop

    Do While Sheet2.Cells(i, 10).Value <> 0
       Sheet3.Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 10)
       i = i - 1
    Loop

    Do While Sheet2.Cells(i, 6).Value <> 2
       Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
       i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

This script populates information in the correct sheet as well as the correct columns, at least until it encounters an empty cell from Sheet2.  At this point is moves on to the next "Do While" instead of referring to the next non blank cell.

I've also encountered a Runtime Error 6- Overflow with this specific line:

```
Do While Sheet2.Cells(i, 6).Value <> 2
   Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
   i = i + 1 <<<<----- ERROR??
```

I'm fairly certain that the Overflow Error is a result of `Dim i as Integer` vs. `Dim i as String`, but then again I've pretty much but working by trial and error, moving portions of script around and playing with expressions/functions.

As mentioned before I'm new to VBA.  I'm also the kind of guy that learns by doing as well.  I've looked all over different forums, youtube videos, etc. trying to create a script that works the way I want it to.

### UPDATE

Thanks for the quick help and recommendations. I realized I didn't give near enough information in my first post.

1.)  I don't need/want to leave an empty cell on sheet3.  The script is now looping but not skipping over blanks  if that makes sense?

```
For example:
     doing    need to do
      101         101
      102         102
                  104
      104         105
      105         106
      106
```

I'm stil running off the end of the world as well so to speak.  For some reason the Debug Function is bringing up this line

```
 i = i + 1
```

2.) the line:

```
   Do While Sheet2.Cells(i, 6).Value <> 2
     Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6)
```

is supposed to recognize a column of text not numbers.  Not exactly sure if this is having an effect on anything

Thanks again everyone.

**UPDATE 3:**

I've got rid of the Error Messages and corrected all the expressions in the script. Also, I found that instead of using `Do Until....... And........` had zero results.  I had to go back to `Do While` and substitute an `Or` statement vs. the former.

So far the script is working better than I had expected.  Thank You all for the help and insight.

Good news aside,  I still need to figure out how to compose an "IF" statement so that the script will skip over blank cells in `sheet2.cells(i, 1)` and not import present values for that row in the 2 adjacent columns

Here is the current and running script:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long
i = 3  

Do While (Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(i, 10))) Or (Sheet3.Cells(i, 4).Value <> 0)
   Sheet3.Cells(i, 4).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 10).Value
   i = i + 1
Loop

i = 3
Do While (Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))) Or (Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value <> 0)
   Sheet3.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
   i = i + 1
Loop

i = 3
Do While (Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(i, 6))) Or (Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value <> 0)
   Sheet3.Cells(i, 3).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 6).Value
   i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Thank you again everyone.  Hope I can return the favor in the near future.

Comment: You might need to set i = 1 in between the loops.
Otherwise it is taking a previous value of i from the earlier loop increments

Comment: Also when a cell is empty you probably need to stop 
so check for empty cells. Otherwise you will continue skipping cells because they are empty and <> 2

Comment: Also `Dim i as Long`.  It is better to restart each loop from `i=1` upward. When you work downward you may hit `i = 0` and the range method will raise a runtime error.

Comment: Re. #1 in your update - how do you know when you're done?  You want to ignore blank cells and keep going, right?  Is there a cell below `106` that has the value `0` or some other marker?

Comment: I figured out a few things and got rid of the Over Flow error by changing       i=1 to     i=3

from there all i had to do was change the expressions so that they all matched.

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts:

- As @dgorti said, make sure to set `i` before each `Do` loop to be the index of the row you want to start with.
- `Dim` any integer value as `Long`, not `Integer`.  `Long` is 32 bits; `Integer` is 16.
- To skip over empty cells, use `IsEmpty`.  For example, in your first loop: **Edited**

  ```
  Do Until (Not IsEmpty(Sheet2.Cells(i, 1))) and (Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0)
  ```
- **Edit** And, as @A.S.H. points out, you should also range-check `i`.  Since VBA doesn't have short-circuit operators, I would do that at the end of your loop:

  ```
  Do ...
      ...   'vvvvv representable in a Long
      If i = 65536 Then Exit Do    ' Or If i = 1... for loops that count down
      i = i + 1
  Loop
  ```

  That way you never run off the end.

**Edit** I fixed the test above — you want to run until you hit a non-empty cell with a value of `0`, right?  So `Do Until` (which is a real thing :) ) loops until exactly that condition holds.  The `Not IsEmpty()` prevents the test against `0` from giving the wrong result on blank cells.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: well that didn't turn out quite how I'd hoped.  I'll explain better in an edit

Comment: Sorry - fixed the condition in the answer.  If it's still not working, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41751435/edit) to add the updated code below the original code (don't change the original code, or later readers won't understand the original question).